# How to heal/fill this type of damage to a mesh?

Tags: modeling

Let's say we have a pattern of vertices, like so:
[image]

I have a grave weakness in my modeling: it's quite an arduous process for me to fill those in!

Would someone be so kind as to tell me the best way to "heal" these meshes, ie, fill them in with an edge/vertice pattern that more or less matches the one I deleted?

Without knowing this, a simple mistake can be deadly..

(PS: Yes, one of those is just missing a face.)

Comment: I know this may seem obvious, but why doesn't Ctrl+Z help you undo it? If you need to repair it, you can select the vertices and press `F`. I will add an answer

Comment: It's both a technical point and, in the case of not realizing you had some extra things selected (and thus if you were to continue to work) a practical point.

Comment: Alright, I posted an answer. Does it help/solve your problem? Let me know by commenting if it doesn't ;)

Answer (score 5):

**For a flat mesh:**
You can repair most issues like this by holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> and then right-clicking on the boundary edge. Now the perimiter of the hole will be selected. Now press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> *> Grid Fill*. If it is a space with only four vertices/edges, you can simply press <kbd>F</kbd> to create the new face.

[image: Repairing A Mesh]

**For a curved mesh:** This is a little more complex, but still can be done. You will need to set the cursor position to the center of the curve/sphere. Now set the Pivot Point to 3D Cursor. You now are able to duplicate vertices on each loop and rotate them to the correct positions in the mesh. Simply select each quad of vertices and press <kbd>F</kbd>. This is more tedious, but is still effective.

[image: Repairing a rounded mesh]

Comment: Is there a way in settings to make blender use something other than an alt key?  My OS is just fascinated with the Alt key, and blender never receives that stroke!

Comment: Yes, in the user preferences you can search for the commands and set them to something else, however I don't know the name of the command for selecting a loopcut.

Comment: @user1833028 Just found something here: [go to number six on the list](http://www.blenderguru.com/articles/25-useful-blender-tricks-that-arent-so-obvious/)

Comment: Thanks, I've fixed it in fact.  I'll look over the list though, you've been a big help.

Comment: No problem, always glad to :)

Comment: I don't think the method for the sphere works on my example... there is not enough information to select use F!  I have to get these triangle things, and then it Looks all funny... like this: http://i.imgur.com/vDt5Co6.png

Comment: Using Ctrl F does exactly that,I explained it in my answer. Please re-read it. The final GIF is the most instructive