# what is the best way to patch a hole in a spherical mesh

Tags: mesh

[image]

how would you fix the hole so that its even like the other parts of the mesh?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28851/how-to-heal-fill-this-type-of-damage-to-a-mesh/ and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48339/how-to-reverse-engineer-mesh-created-out-of-smooth-curves-with-a-missing-chunk

Answer (score 2):

Select the edges around the hole and do "Grid Fill".

(Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> and select **Grid Fill** or use the menu: Mesh->Faces->Grid Fill)

Then set the span and offset to get the desired result.

[image]